# How to target a specific Ionic view with $rootScope.$broadcast

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Using Ionic, calling $rootScope.$broadcast("$ionicView.enter") will trigger all child views having an event handler for the $ionicView.enter event.

How can I narrow this down to target the handler for a specific view?

Comment: What are you trying to target. Are you trying to target entering a view like do you want to know when a view in being navigated to?

Comment: No, I'm trying to programatically trigger the $ionicView.enter event-handler of a specific view. (My use case is the view is already active, but the event handler needs to be re-run if there was a network connection error the first time it was run)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any code samples, but it sounds like what you are describing doesn't require triggering an event with specific data, but listening to the event w/ specific data.

Perhaps this snippet can help you:

```
$rootScope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", function( scopes, states ) {
        //here's an example of storing network error state in rootscope 
        //and some random important state that requires your data to be refreshed 

        if( $rootScope.networkErrorOccurred && states.stateName == "myImportantState" ) {
           //refresh data due to network error code goes here 
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please re-read the question again. Your answer does not address the question. For example, $rootScope.$on( "$ionicView.enter", ...) will handle enter events for ALL views. I am only interested in one specific view. And the question is how to construct the event to target the existing enter event handler in only one specific view/scope.

Comment: I was providing a possible answer based on the comment about network connection errors. You should be a little less snarky to people trying to help you. 

The answer to your question is it is not possible to broadcast an event and have listeners of that event not fire.  

You can only take action based on params, like I provided in the example, but you can't ignore it.

If you are intent on only triggering one event, you should use a custom event you create yourself like 'app.NetworkError' and listening to that event and recall the code from the $ionicView.enter event here.

Comment: Also, is .$emit("$ionicView.enter") an option instead of $broadcast? Given that you didn't provide any code examples, it's hard to know for sure. 

If it is possible, then you can set stopPropagation on your listener to true so that it does not propagate up the scope stack.

Answer (score 0):

When calling $rootScope.$broadcast("$ionicView.enter") the "states" object is none existent and hence you cannot rely on the stateName.

But, you can add it yourself, like so:

```
$rootScope.$broadcast('$ionicView.enter', {stateName: 'myImportantState'});
```

This will make Travis example working.

---

The other way I can think of is to save a reference to the view's scope and emit an event directly on it.

I must say I wouldn't recommend it, but maybe that's what you're looking for.

**Inside the view's controller**

```
app.controller('someViewCtrl', function($scope) {
  //Save a reference to the view's scope, using window for brevity
  window.someViewScope = $scope;
}
```

**Somewhere else in the app**

```
window.someViewScope.$emit('$ionicView.enter')
```